# nested NSArray value change in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I have a nested array :

```
NSArray *cellInfos = @[
@[
  @{MenuCellId:@"1", MenuCellCounterKey:"0"},
  @{MenuCellId:@"2", MenuCellCounterKey:"0"}
],
@[
  @{MenuCellId:@"3", MenuCellCounterKey:"0"},
  @{MenuCellId:@"4", MenuCellCounterKey:"0"}
]];
```

How can I change the MenuCellCounterKey value by MenuCellId ?

thanks

Comment: Firstly you will need `NSMutableArray` , because `NSArray` can't be modified.

Comment: Explain your problem more briefly.

Comment: why are there two arrays of the same kinds of dictionaries?

Comment: This is 2 or more section in a tableview.

Comment: In my case the MenuCellCounterKey and the MenuCellId is a constant : NSString const *MenuCellId = @"CellId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need copy the array depth, make sure the array you got is mutable, and the nsdictionary is mutable too,  then traversing the array refer to the layers, compare the MenuCellId, and change the MenuCellCounterKey.

```
NSMutableArray * mutableCellInfos = [cellInfos mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i < mutableCellInfos.count; ++i)
{
    NSMutableArray * mutableSection = [[mutableCellInfos objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
    for (int j = 0; j < mutableSection.count; ++j)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * mutableItem = [[mutableSection objectAtIndex:j] mutableCopy];
        if ([mutableItem objectForKey:@"3"]) {
            [mutableItem setObject:@"new value" forKey:@"3"];
        }

        [mutableSection replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:mutableItem];
    }

    [mutableSection replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mutableSection];
}

cellInfos = mutableCellInfos;
```